# Python web services: Trying to connect to WSDL endpoint using zeep SOAP client gives connection error

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

Python: 2.7.6

zeep: 1.1.0

I'm trying to reach the WSDL endpoint of a web service URL. I'm currently using the zeep SOAP client and have also tried suds (and gotten similar results). When I access the URL from the web or send a curl request to it, I get a response and can see the services. But when I try to access it from zeep (using the python -mzeep [url] command) or suds (by just print(client)) I get a connection error.

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

I have pasted the full error below. Unfortunately I am unable to share the URL here so I'm changing it for my post.

In my code I have the following

```
from zeep import Client
endpoint_url = 'http://12.345.678.90:8080/PathGoesHere?wsdl'
client = Client(endpoint_url)
```

I have also tried the following

```
sudo python -mzeep http://12.345.678.90:8080/PathGoesHere?wsdl
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/__main__.py", line 86, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/__main__.py", line 75, in main
    client = Client(args.wsdl_file, transport=transport)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/client.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.wsdl = Document(wsdl, self.transport)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 65, in __init__
    root_definitions = Definition(self, document, self.location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.parse_types(doc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/wsdl.py", line 272, in parse_types
    self.types.add_documents(schema_nodes, self.location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 96, in add_documents
    document = self.create_new_document(node, location)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 183, in create_new_document
    schema.load(self, node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/xsd/schema.py", line 349, in load
    visitor.visit_schema(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/xsd/visitor.py", line 108, in visit_schema
    self.process(node, parent=parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/xsd/visitor.py", line 49, in process
    result = visit_func(self, node, parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/xsd/visitor.py", line 155, in visit_import
    schema_node = load_external(location, self.schema._transport)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/xsd/utils.py", line 59, in load_external
    response = transport.load(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 111, in load
    content = self._load_remote_data(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/transports.py", line 126, in _load_remote_data
    response = self.session.get(url, timeout=self.load_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 487, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='host.goes.here', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /PathGoesHere?xsd=xsd0 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbf2c442390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

I'm not sure why it works through browser/curl but not python SOAP clients. Is there something I should be changing in my endpoint URL like setting the port later? I tried that with suds and it gave me a 404 error because of an invalid URL. How should I approach this problem/what else can I try?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First come to my mind is, are you behind a firewall? This is not a wired error, just because of the URL is not accessible.

For most company environment, you can visit a URL by browser but you cannot access it from command line (or a python library). The reason is, the company policy has been applied to your computer, and the browser uses a proxy script (a pac) file to determine which proxy to use.

If you could share how did you test the URL, which will be very helpful.

Can you please simply use the command `ping` to test if that URL is accessible.

Comment: I also pinged the ip `ping 12.345.678.90` and got a response

Comment: sorry i meant to say


The ways I tested the URL were: 1. Access url on local browser (works) 
2. send a curl request from my vm to the URL (works) 
3. For suds: 
`client = Client(http://12.345.678.90:8080/PathGoesHere?wsdl, cachingpolicy=1)
 print(client)` 
(does not work)
4. For zeep:
`sudo python -mzeep http://12.345.678.90:8080/PathGoesHere?wsdl`
(does not work)

Comment: the box running the service provider has the firewall turned off

Answer (score -1):

In my situation it seems that changing my url endpoint from

```
http://12.345.678.90:8080/PathGoesHere?wsdl
```

to

```
http://12.345.678.90:8080/PathGoesHere?singleWsdl
```

did the trick